# Múltiples cajas de diálogo en WinAPI32 C++

Tags: c++, diálogo

Tengo un proyecto que he realizado en `.DLL`, pero tengo 3 cajas de dialogo, IDD_DIALOG1(el principal) y tengo otras 2 cajas de dialogo IDD_DIALOG2 y IDD_DIALOG3, de lo cual dentro del IDD_DIALOG1 he insertado 2 BUTTONS que quiero que hagan un llamado a cada caja de dialogo por ejemplo: BUTTON1 que al dar clic abra el IDD_DIALOG2 y el BUTTON2 abra el IDD_DIALOG3.

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "resource.h"

HINSTANCE H_DIALOG1, H_DIALOG2, H_DIALOG3;

BOOL CALLBACK call_Dialogo2(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
BOOL CALLBACK call_Dialogo3(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

BOOL CALLBACK call_Dialogo1(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

BOOL CALLBACK call_Dialogo1(HWND hDialogo, UINT mensaje, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (mensaje)
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (LOWORD(wParam))
            {
            case IDCANCEL:
                EndDialog(hDialogo, false);
                break;

            case IDC_BUTTON1:
                DialogBox(H_DIALOG2, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG2), 0, call_Dialogo2);
                break;

            case IDC_BUTTON2:
                DialogBox(H_DIALOG3, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG3), 0, call_Dialogo3);
                break;
            }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
BOOL CALLBACK call_Dialogo2(HWND hDialogo, UINT mensaje, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (mensaje)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hDialogo, false);
            break;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
BOOL CALLBACK call_Dialogo3(HWND hDialogo, UINT mensaje, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (mensaje)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hDialogo, false);
            break;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta ni entiendo el código ¿Cómo se deben abrir los diálogos 2 y 3 si no hay ni una llamada a su apertura? Sólo abres el diálogo 1 en `WinMain`. Y tu programa ¿Es una dll o un exe? Si es lo primero no debería tener `WinMain` y si es lo segundo deberías cargar la dll que te abre los otros diálogos. ¿Podrías clarificar tu pregunta?

Comment: Listo, ya clarifique mi pregunta. Disculpa si no me explique correctamente.